Putting Legend completely outside the plot in right center
I am trying to create a plot where the legend will be in the right center but completely outside the plot. I am following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75453792/3587282 and using Matplotlib 3.7 but the legend still stays on the plot partially.

Here is my complete code to reproduce this image:
import os
import json
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns;

sns.set(style="ticks");
sns.set_context("paper")  # talk, notebook, paper
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

# Set font family, bold, and font size
font = {'size': 16}  # font = {'family':'normal', 'weight':'normal', 'size': 12}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
# Avoid Type 3 fonts: http://phyletica.org/matplotlib-fonts/
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42
plt.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
# plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
# plt.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0


cfg = {
    'x_label': 'Step',
    'y_label': 'Return',
    'show': False,
    # 'imgType': 'png',
    'imgType': 'pdf',
    'ci': 'se',
    'runs': 20,
    # 'loc': 'best'
    'loc': 'outside center right'
}


def nchain_best():
    label_list = ['DQN', 'Noisy-Net', 'Bootstrapped DQN', 'Adam LMCDQN', 'ULMCDQN', 'FG-LMCDQN', 'FG-ULMCDQN']
    color_list = ['tab:olive', 'tab:cyan', 'tab:purple', 'tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:red', 'tab:green', 'tab:brown']
    x_mean = np.array([25, 50, 75, 100])

    # Data with 20 runs
    y_mean = {
        'DQN': np.array([9.40, 5.52, 5.19, 5.05]),
        'FG-ULMCDQN': np.array([10, 9.85, 9.80, 9.80]),
        'FG-LMCDQN': np.array([9.50, 8.75, 8.46, 8.07]),
        'ULMCDQN': np.array([9.63, 9.73, 7.90, 8.02]),
        'Adam LMCDQN': np.array([8.55, 7.31, 6.08, 6.04]),
        'Noisy-Net': np.array([6.51, 1.95, 0.98, 0.90]),
        'Bootstrapped DQN': np.array([9.70, 7.56, 6.36, 3.57]),
        'LSVI-PHE': np.array([9.86, 9.86, 9.72, 9.50])
    }
    y_ci = {
        'DQN': np.array([0.44, 0.99, 0.37, 0.19])*2.093,
        'FG-ULMCDQN': np.array([0, 0.14, 0.15, 0.19])*2.093,
        'FG-LMCDQN': np.array([0.26, 0.69, 0.52, 0.47])*2.093,
        'ULMCDQN': np.array([0.13, 0.12, 0.88, 0.70])*2.093,
        'Adam LMCDQN': np.array([0.64, 0.86, 1.04, 0.86])*2.093,
        'Noisy-Net': np.array([1.02, 0.85, 0.55, 0.14])*2.093,
        'Bootstrapped DQN': np.array([0.10, 0.64, 0.79, 0.73])*2.093,
        'LSVI-PHE': np.array([0.13, 0.13, 0.26, 0.31])*2.093
    }


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(len(label_list)):
        label = label_list[i]
        # Plot
        plt.plot(x_mean, y_mean[label], linewidth=2, color=color_list[i], label=label, marker='o', markersize=7)
        plt.fill_between(x_mean, y_mean[label] - y_ci[label], y_mean[label] + y_ci[label], facecolor=color_list[i],
                         alpha=0.3)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xlabel('N', fontsize=18)
    ax.set_ylabel('Return', fontsize=18)
    plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
    ax.set_xlim(20, 105)
    ax.set_ylim(0, None)
    ax.set_xticks(ticks=[25, 50, 75, 100])
    # Set legend
    # ax.legend(loc=cfg['loc'], frameon=False, fontsize=14) # older version
    fig.legend(loc='outside center right', frameon=False, fontsize=14)
    # Adjust figure layout
    fig.tight_layout()
    # Save and show
    image_path = f'./figures/nchain_best.{cfg["imgType"]}'
    ax.get_figure().savefig(image_path)
    if cfg['show']:
        plt.show()
    plt.clf()  # clear figure
    plt.cla()  # clear axis
    plt.close()  # close window




if __name__ == "__main__":
    nchain_best()


plt.tight_layout() doesn't take the figure legend into account, causing the overlap.  Changing it to ax.legend(..., loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5)) should work. (plt.legend() is an alternative for ax.legend, not fig.legend).  The post you link to also suggests that fig.legend() would work nice together with "constrained layout" (not to be confused with plt.tight_layout()).
